# Filtering results of a many to many relationship using data in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join, model

I have rails application with two models, StudentProfile and ClassProfile that are associated via a join table (model Enrollment).

In my ClassProfile model, I have:

```
has_many :enrollments
has_many :student_profiles, through: :enrollments
```

and in my StudentProfile model, I have:

```
has_one :enrollment
has_one :class_profile, through: :enrollment
```

My enrollments table also has a status integer field.

I would like to put a method in the ClassProfile model called "roster" that returns all the student_profiles that have an enrollment status of 1. Right now, I have the following:

```
def roster
  self.student_profiles
end
```

Needless to say, all this does is return all students in a class, regardless of enrollment status. I feel like this should be simple, but I've seen no examples of how to add filtering on the join table (enrollments). Is this something I can accomplish in the ClassProfile model, or do I need to do something in Enrollment (or elsewhere)?

**Update**

From looking through the query reference mentioned by @QMFNP, here's the code that worked:

```
self.student_profiles.includes(:enrollment).where('enrollments.status = ?', 1)
```

Needed to change `:enrollments` to `:enrollment` because it's a `has_one` association. And the `enrollments` field that I'm filtering on is `status`, so changed `enrollments.id` to `enrollments.status`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by specifying your query conditions on the association like so:

```
def roster
  self.student_profiles.includes(:enrollment).where('enrollments.status = ?', 1)
end
```

This should return your expected results. More information about querying on Active Record associations can be found here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: As presented, it didn't work. However your answer (and instructions to look at the query guide) prompted me to look at the query interface. From that, two changes to your answer made it work correctly. I've edited it to reflect the changes (don't know how long it will take to be "reviewed." Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Small oversight on my part. Glad I could help.